# Script stops working after load more function is initiated

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site http://taste.fourseasons.com/ingredients/

At the bottom of the main content section, there's an option to call more posts, but once they are called, the script that allows users to vote on them is not enabled on the new posts. If the vote up button is clicked, the user is brought to the top of the page as if it has an <"a href="#">

I assume that the voting script is getting initiated on load, and but not triggering the voting button on posts that are loaded after the original document is loaded?

Any thoughts?

thanks!

Okay, so here's what I think is the relative code. I tried to set up a jsfiddle, but I think it's all still alittle over my head at the moment. From what I have gathered, I need to create a call back function so that once the new posts are added to the DOM, the original voting script gets reloaded. Hope that makes sense and thanks for taking the time with an aspiring scriptor!

From function.php:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_add_votes_options", "add_votes_options");
function add_votes_options() {
$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'voting_nonce_'.$postid))
    return;

$voter_ips = get_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", true);
if(!empty($voter_ips) && in_array($ip, $voter_ips)) {
    echo "null";
    die(0);
} else {
    $voter_ips[] = $ip;
    update_post_meta($postid, "voter_ips", $voter_ips);
}   

$current_votes = get_post_meta($postid, "votes", true);
$new_votes = intval($current_votes) + 1;
update_post_meta($postid, "votes", $new_votes);
$return = $new_votes>1 ? $new_votes : $new_votes;
echo $return;
die(0);
}
```

And here's how it's being pulled into onto the page:

```
<div class="grid_row_1">
<div class="grid_col">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>      
<div class="clear"></div>   
</div>

<div class="grid_row_1">
<div class="grid_col ingredients post-holder" data-direction="DESC" data-    
order="date">       
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=15&post_type=ingredient&paged='.$paged);  
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
    foreach($ingredient_images as $meta_box) { 
    $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ingredient-images', true); 
    switch($meta_box['name']){
        case 'ingredient_thumb': $feature_thumb = $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] 
]; break;
        case 'ingredient_status': $feature_thumb_show = $data[ $meta_box[ 
'name' ] ]; break;
        }               
    } 
    switch($feature_thumb_show){
        case 1: $type='suggested'; break;
        case 2: $type='accepted'; break;
        case 3: $type='featured'; break;
    }
    $theDate= get_the_date( 'o-n-j' );
    $time = strtotime($theDate);
    $one_week_ago = strtotime('-1 week');
    switch($count){
        case 0: echo '<div class="post one-quarter-sub-col-above-480 one-half-sub-col-at-480 first '.$type.'">';       $count++; break;
        case 1: echo '<div class="post one-quarter-sub-col-above-480 one-half-sub-col-at-480 last-at-480 '.$type.'">';  $count++; break;
        case 2: echo '<div class="post one-quarter-sub-col-above-480 one-half-sub-col-at-480 first-at-480 '.$type.'">'; $count++; break;
        case 3: echo '<div class="post one-quarter-sub-col-above-480 one-half-sub-col-at-480 last '.$type.'">';            $count = 0; break;
    }

    $votes = get_post_meta($post->ID, "votes", true);
    $votes = !empty($votes) ? $votes : "0";

    $hasvoted = $_COOKIE['better_votes_'.$post->ID];
    $hasvoted = explode(",", $hasvoted);

    if(in_array($post->ID, $hasvoted)) {
        $vtext = "VOTED";
        $class = 'unvote-sm';
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $voter_ips = get_post_meta($post->ID, "voter_ips", true);
        if(!empty($voter_ips) && in_array($ip, $voter_ips)) {
            $vtext = "VOTED";
            $class = 'unvote-sm';
        } else {
            $vtext = "VOTE";
            $class = 'vote-sm';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <?php if(function_exists('wp_nonce_field')) wp_nonce_field('voting_nonce_'.$post->ID.'', 'voting_nonce_'.$post->ID.''); ?>
        <div class="bg-white pad-lr10 pad-t10 border-lightgrey margin-b10">
            <div class="photo-wrapper ratio-16-9 text-white">
                <?php if($feature_thumb_show!=3): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/blank_landscape.gif"></a>
                <div class="image-overlay full-width full-height align-center bg-lightblue">
                    <table class="layout-vert-center full-width full-height">
                        <tr><td><a class="header font-30 tk3 leading-tight" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $feature_thumb; ?>&amp;w=220&amp;h=130&amp;a=t"></a>
                <div class="image-overlay bottom bg-black bg-opaque-50 pad-5">
                    <a class="header font-30 tk3 leading-tight" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $time > $one_week_ago ) {?>
                <div class="image-overlay"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/icon_new.png"></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="font-16 leading-medium">
                <div class="one-half">
                    <a href="#" class="vote icon-text-link disp-block border-right-lightgrey pad-tb5 pad-r5 tk3" data-post="<?php echo $post->ID ?>">
                        <div class="vote-text pad-t5 float-left"><?php echo $vtext; ?></div>
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <div class="vote-count float-left text-medgrey pad-t5"><?php echo $votes; ?></div>
                            <span class="icon-holder float-left <?php echo $class; ?>"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="one-half">
                    <a href="#" class="icon-text-link disp-block pad-tb5 pad-l5 tk3">
                        <div class="pad-t5 float-left hide-at-768">COMMENT</div>
                        <div class="float-right"><div class="float-left text-medgrey pad-t5"></div><span class="icon-holder comment-sm float-left pad-t5"><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></span></div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Then the new posts get added with:

```
    <div class="grid_row_1">
    <div class="grid_col">
        <div class="border-top-black margin-tb20">
            <div class="align-center"><a class="action-btn pad-lr50 tk3 view-more" href="#">SHOW MORE</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks again for any insight!

Comment: It sounds to me like you've got the right idea. If the event handling script is invoked before those new elements are brought into the DOM, then unless the attaching code accounts for new elements via some sort of delegation process the new elements are pretty much SOL there. Without seeing actual code it would be tough to say for certain, though.

Comment: @user15624: Could you please post the relevant script and HTML output? As soon as your link is dead this question will make little sense for future users with a possible similar issue.

Comment: Thanks @natlee75, that's what I thought. I'm a bit new to js, wondering if you might be able to recommend a place where I can research a snippet that would help with that delegation process?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I'll have to do some digging, but I will, thanks.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I can't seem to figure out how to add the code, as I keep getting an error stating that it's too many characters, should I start a new question and then direct people from this one there? thanks.

Comment: @user15624: Are you trying to add the code to the comments? Edit your question and add the relevant HTML/Script there. In addition a good way is to also start a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) and start getting the code to work in there. That way you can copy only the relevant HTML/Script to demonstrate the issue. Fiddles are great for sharing an issue letting anyone use it as a sandbox to test different solutions. Also most of the time while users build fiddles they realise what was wrong in the process :)

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisWahl, I'll do that now.